# Generate random integer numbers in C, not within a range

Tags: c, random

I want to generate 100 nodes with random x and y co ordinates. But i do not want to specify any range. Like rand(100) will generate numbers only between 1 to 100. But i want the numbers distributed over a large region and i want them to be random. How can i implement it using C?
i have tried:

```
 int gen_rand_position(void)  
{  
     int i,j,a[100],b[100];  
    for(i=0,j=0;i<100,j<100;i++,j++)  
{
    x=rand();  
        y=rand();  
    a[i]=x;  
    b[j]=y;  
}  
}
```

This not choosing randomly. Can i have more efficient random function?

Comment: If you want a bigger range, give it a bigger number `rand(abignumber)`

Comment: @BaliC This question is tagged C. In C `rand()` is prototyped as `int rand(void);`; If you apply it to `abignumber`, it's either a static error or undefined behavior depending whether the header was properly included.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have a range otherwise what are you going to do with an infinite number?

With no arguments - rand() will return an integer between 0 and RAND_MAX ( normally 32765).

If you need a number larger than this you could combine two rand() numbers.  There are complicated statistical arguments about the best way to combine random numbers so you don't change the randomness but I don't think you need to worry about that.

Edit: since RAND_MAX is (in this case) a 15bit number, to get a 30bit range multiply two rand() together, to get a 32bit range multiply again - it may wrap around but that doesn't change the randomness (significantly).

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a random number distributed over the entire `int` range, combine the random bits from multiple calls to `rand()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int large_rand()
{
  const int RAND_BITS = 15;  /* covers stdc minimum for RAND_MAX */
  const int INT_BITS = 8 * sizeof(int);
  const int ITERS = (INT_BITS + RAND_BITS - 1) / RAND_BITS;
  int i, result = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
    result <<= RAND_BITS;
    result |= rand() & ~(~0U << RAND_BITS);
  }
  return result;
}
```

To get a random number in the desired range, use `large_rand() % (MAX + 1)`, where `MAX` is the largest number you want to get.